# Opening *.TPL as HTML highlighted as standard

Tags: ultraedit

How can I make UltraEdit 14 open *.tpl files with HTML highligthing as standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the file extension, TPL, in file `WORDFILE.UEW`. The line starting with

```
/L3"HTML" HTML_LANG
```

ends with

```
File Extensions = HTM HTML SHTML HTT HTA HTX CFM JSP PHP PHTML ASP TMPL
```

Add TPL at the end:

```
File Extensions = HTM HTML SHTML HTT HTA HTX CFM JSP PHP PHTML ASP TMPL TPL
```

It takes effect immediately, there is no need to restart UltraEdit.

The location of `WORDFILE.UEW` can be found by opening menu Advanced/Configuration/Editor Display/Syntax Highlighting/Full directory path for wordfiles.